# How to destroy an object once it leaves the screen?

Tags: java, arraylist, processing

In my code I have a class, `Key` that can create a key at a random coordinate.  When a key is pressed, that key is added to an `ArrayList`. The `ArrayList` is iterated in the `draw()` method, and the key falls at a certain velocity. Multiple keys can be displayed at once. I want to remove a `Key` from the `ArrayList` once it leaves the view of the screen.

I have tried something like `if (key.location.y - textAscent() > height) {keys.remove(key)}` which either causes the program to stop working, or causes a letter to stop moving but remain in view once it reaches the bottom of the screen. Any suggestions?

edit: by stop working, I mean the program freezes and I get this error:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:909)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:859)
    at FallingLetters.draw(FallingLetters.java:35)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2426)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$12.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1557)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:316)
```

I don't know what to do with it.

```
PFont f;
ArrayList<Key> keys;

void setup() {
  fullScreen(1);
  f=createFont("Bahnschrift", 300, true);
  textFont(f);
  keys = new ArrayList();
}

void draw() {
  fill(#FF5254);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);

  for (Key k : keys) {
    k.display();
    k.fall();
  }
}


void keyPressed() {
  keys.add(new Key());
}

class Key {
  PVector location, velocity;
  char k;
  color c;

  public Key() {
    this.c = 0;
    this.k=key;
    this.location = new PVector(random(width), random(height));
    this.velocity = new PVector(0, int(random(1, 11)));
  }

  void display() {
    fill(c);
    text(k, location.x, location.y);
  }

  void fall() {
    this.location.add(velocity);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luke's answer is already pretty good, but another approach I like to take in simple Processing sketches is to use a basic `for` loop and loop backwards over the list.

```
for(int i = keys.size()-1; i >= 0; i--){
  Key key = keys.get(i);
  key.display();
  key.fall();
}
```

Now if you remove a key inside the `fall()` function, you loop will continue functioning fine.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arraylists#removing-from-an-arraylist) is a tutorial on ArrayLists in Processing, including the approach I just outlined.

Comment: Very nice, I suppose I'm used to the order of the list being important, but in processing it is quite the contrary! Also I enjoyed your tutorial, very comprehensive.